# AWS Instance with 30 GB RAM, still running out of Memory and High CPU usage with small app

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cpu-usage, memory-usage

**EDIT (15th June 2018)** - I have resolved the issue. It was Postgres where some queries were taking more than 15 seconds. Most of the queries were for the same type of pages so I just removed that. This is what I did -

1. Enable Postgres logging (I enabled for more than 3-second queries)
2. Check the log file and find which queries are taking more time. There were few taking 15 seconds.
3. I looked at the code. There was no indexing in one table so I created it. The issue was due to one unoptimized query. Since it wasn't needed, I just removed it from the code.

---

We are on 30 GB AWS instance running a Ruby on Rails app using Passenger + Apache.

Though the App Postgres DB has millions of records, The DB size is few GB only. Now I am finding the server to always be on High Usage. Here is the server load and process running.

**What can I do to diagnose the issue or optimize the server?** as the app keeps crashing due to high CPU or Memory usage with only 20 users online.

Here is the output of commands -

**uptime**

[image]

**sar -q**

[image]

**top**

[image]

**vmstat 10 6**

[image]

**iostat 2**

[image]

**ps -eo 'pcpu,%cpu,pid,comm' | grep -v '%CPU   PID COMMAND' | sort -n**
(last 20 rows)

[image]

**ps -eo 'rss,%mem,pcpu,%cpu,pid,comm' | grep -v '%CPU   PID COMMAND' | sort -n**

[image]

Comment: MySQL and Postgres are using a lot of CPU. I think you need to look at indexing, slow queries and such rather than server issues. Best hire a DBA or do some reading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really appreciate it. Anything else I can work on? I am looking at various resources on the web now and will optimize Postgres.

Comment: Define "crashing". Does syslog indicate the oom killer is terminating processes?  Is your application timing out or having other poor performance?

Comment: @JohnMahowald Crashing means the app doesn't load in the browser. Memory usage shows full 100% used and CPU shows it is under high load. Though I can still login to server via SSH to restart apache and free memory by removing log files which bring things to normal for some time.

Comment: We don't have visibility into your app to see what it doing, get a DBA or other professional services to look at it and give you a capacity assessment. And try separating your database and web tiers onto different hosts, you can isolate problems and auto scale easier that way.

Comment: @Tim Yes, the issue was Postgres only. I hired a DBA specialist, we spent few hours and resolved the issue. There were some queries which were not of any use and taking lot of CPU so we just removed that code. I have updated the question at the bottom with the EDIT on what we did for others to look at too. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @iCyborg, your "edit" is actually a useful answer IMO.  You should consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, please put an answer in to your question, otherwise people will come in and try to help, and it stays marked as unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. It was Postgres where some queries were taking more than 15 seconds. Most of the queries were for the same type of pages so I just removed that. This is what I did -

1. Enable Postgres logging (I enabled for more than 3-second queries). Open postgresql.conf file and enable logging.

   sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
2. Check the log file and find which queries are taking more time.

   sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
3. There were few queries taking 15 seconds. I looked at the code. There was no indexing in one table so I created it. The issue was due to one unoptimized query. Since it wasn't needed, I just removed it from the code.